# Existence of colimit-dense subset

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a locally presentable category and let $I$ be a full subcategory of $C$ closed under colimits. Does $I$ have a colimit-dense subset of objects? (I hope that this Q doesn't depend on the chosen set theory.)

Comment: It seems likely that the question is indeed set-theoretical. Under Vopěnka's principle, such a subcategory is automatically accessible (hence, locally presentable).

Comment: Yes but I wonder if there is another argument.